# being sold vs. selling?

Tags: usage

***sell*** is used both as intransitive and transitive verb. Sometimes the line between the two usages seems vague to me since I haven't found the exact grammar(or usage) rules. My rule of thumb says (B) is not acceptable, but I don't know why.

- (A) A neighbor drops by and starts telling you both about the terrific
  new wines ***being sold*** at the liquor store just down the street.
- (B) A neighbor drops by and starts telling you both about the terrific
  new wines ***selling*** at the liquor store just down the street.

> Psychological research has shown that people naturally divide up
> cognitive labor, often without thinking about it. Imagine you’re
> cooking up a special dinner with a friend. You’re a great cook, but
> your friend is the wine expert, an amateur sommelier. A neighbor drops
> by and starts telling you both about the terrific new wines being sold
> at the liquor store just down the street. There are many new wines, so
> there’s a lot to remember. How hard are you going to try to remember
> what the neighbor has to say about which wines to buy? Why bother when
> the information would be better retained by the wine expert sitting
> next to you? If your friend wasn’t around, you might try harder. After
> all, it would be good to know what a good wine would be for the
> evening’s festivities. But your friend, the wine expert, is likely to
> remember the information without even trying.

[The Knowledge Illusion: Why We Never Think Alone](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=2xuMDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA120&lpg=PA120&dq=You%E2%80%99re%20a%20great%20cook,%20but%20your%20friend%20is%20the%20wine%20expert,%20an%20amateur%20sommelier.%20A%20neighbor%20drops%20by%20and%20starts%20telling%20you%20both%20about%20the%20terrific%20new%20wines&source=bl&ots=NWGoCfqTcN&sig=ACfU3U1OzMGlafrorleHJWRa2kZq5d1MzQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj7v43g5qz1AhVW-WEKHSmCCeEQ6AF6BAgOEAM#v=onepage&q=You%E2%80%99re%20a%20great%20cook%2C%20but%20your%20friend%20is%20the%20wine%20expert%2C%20an%20amateur%20sommelier.%20A%20neighbor%20drops%20by%20and%20starts%20telling%20you%20both%20about%20the%20terrific%20new%20wines&f=false)

Comment: Both are correct. Where I live (USA, South) the first sentence is preferable.

Comment: Usually "B" would be a little more defined... *"...terrific new wines **they are selling** at the liquor store..."*. Also from the USA but in the North, I wouldn't hear (B) spoken without that part...

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to use **sell**, meaning "to exchange for money", is the simplest, either active

> The liquor store sells red wine.
> The clerk is selling that woman a bottle of red wine.

or passive.

> Red wine is sold by the liquor store.

**Sell** in the intransitive means something like "is achieving sales".

> The new book is selling really well.

You don't usually see it used without some kind of qualifier, like "selling really well", or "selling poorly".  This explains why (B) seems a little wrong.

Comment: I think that intransitive "sell" can be used with other kinds of qualifiers, too, e.g.: "Apple's new watch is selling for $400." (That is fine in U.S. English, at least.) I suspect that there are different degrees of acceptability for various contexts.